Bounded in probability with the deterministic constant expression
I study the paper in the link below:
https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bernoulli/volume-24/issue-2/Smooth-backfitting-for-additive-modeling-with-small-errors-in-variables/10.3150/16-BEJ898.full
The result of the Proposition 1 (page 1241) in this paper is
\begin{aligned}
\max_{1 \leq i \leq n}|\hat{\xi}^i_{jk}-{\xi}_{jk}^i|=O_p(n^{-(\beta-1)/(2\beta)}), \quad 1\leq j\leq d,1 \leq k \leq L_j, \beta \geq 2.
\end{aligned}
But, in the proof of the Lemma 1 (page 1256), the paper states like this:
We may assume that $\max_{i,j,k} |\hat{\xi}^i_{jk}-{\xi}_{jk}^i| \leq C_0 n^{−(\beta−1)/(2\beta)}$
for some positive constant $C_0$ , due to Proposition 1.
I wonder how this is possible. Generally $\max_{i,j,k} |\hat{\xi}^i_{jk}-{\xi}_{jk}^i| = O_p(n^{−(\beta−1)/(2\beta)})$                 doesn't imply                   $\max_{i,j,k} |\hat{\xi}^i_{jk}-{\xi}_{jk}^i| \leq C_0 n^{−(\beta−1)/(2\beta)}$. I was thinking about defining the event using $C_0$ with probability tending to one, but I still couldn't find the solution.So, basically it seems like the paper claims that $X_n=O_p(1)$ implies $|X_n| \leq C_0$ for some fixed constant $C_0 > 0$.

What definition of "$O_p$" are you using?  The ones most of us are familiar with include "for sufficiently large $n,$" which doesn't seem to be a consideration where you write "doesn't imply."  Is your concern about switching from a probability statement to a statement that appears to be definite?

I'm using the standard bounded in probability $O_p$ notation.Yes,  I'm concerning about switching from a probability statement to a definite statement.

My question was intended as a prompt to suggest an answer to you.  I am thinking that it can help to carefully review the parts of the definition, with special attention to how $n$ is quantified.
